# Yii2 bower error heroku

Tags: php, excel, yii2, bower

I'm using the php yii2 framework, and when I want to install a component I get the following error:

```
composer require codemix / yii2-excelexport
```

error:

```
Using version ^ 2.7 for codemix / yii2-excelexport
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
The "https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/jquery" file could not be downloaded (HTTP / 1.1 502 Bad Gateway)
https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: do not install yiisoft / yii2 2.0.15.1
    - Conclusion: do not install yiisoft / yii2 2.0.15
    - Conclusion: do not install yiisoft / yii2 2.0.14.2
    - Conclusion: do not install yiisoft / yii2 2.0.14.1
    - Conclusion: do not install yiisoft / yii2 2.0.14
    - Conclusion: do not install yiisoft / yii2 2.0.13.3
    - Conclusion: do not install yiisoft / yii2 2.0.13.2
    - Installation request for yiisoft / yii2 (locked at 2.0.12, required as ~ 2.0.5) -> satisfiable by yiisoft / yii2 [2.0.12].
    - Conclusion: do not install yiisoft / yii2 2.0.13.1
    - yii2tech / spreadsheet 1.0.0 requires yiisoft / yii2 ~ 2.0.13 -> satisfiable by yiisoft / yii2 [2.0.13, 2.0.13.1, 2.0.13.2, 2.0.13.3, 2.0.14, 2.0.14.1, 2.0.14.2 , 2.0.15, 2.0.15.1].
    - yii2tech / spreadsheet 1.0.1 requires yiisoft / yii2 ~ 2.0.13 -> satisfiable by yiisoft / yii2 [2.0.13, 2.0.13.1, 2.0.13.2, 2.0.13.3, 2.0.14, 2.0.14.1, 2.0.14.2 , 2.0.15, 2.0.15.1].
    - yii2tech / spreadsheet 1.0.2 requires yiisoft / yii2 ~ 2.0.13 -> satisfiable by yiisoft / yii2 [2.0.13, 2.0.13.1, 2.0.13.2, 2.0.13.3, 2.0.14, 2.0.14.1, 2.0.14.2 , 2.0.15, 2.0.15.1].
    - Conclusion: do not install yiisoft / yii2 2.0.13
    - Installation request for yii2tech / spreadsheet ^ 1.0 -> satisfiable by yii2tech / spreadsheet [1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I read that you have to add the following lines in the .bowerrc file

```
{
      "directory": "vendor / bower",
      "timeout": 120000,
"registry": {
"search": [
"http: // localhost: 8000",
"https://registry.bower.io"
]
}
}
```

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-basic",
    "description": "Yii 2 Basic Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "basic", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.5",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2": "@dev",
        "sammaye/yii2-audittrail": "^1.2",
        "kartik-v/yii2-export": "@dev",
        "ruskid/yii2-csv-importer": "dev-master",
        "moonlandsoft/yii2-phpexcel": "*",
        "wbraganca/yii2-dynamicform": "dev-master",
        "rmrevin/yii2-fontawesome": "~2.17",
        "yiisoft/yii2-jui": "^2.0@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-mpdf": "*",
        "kalyabin/yii2-select-google-map-location": "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datetimepicker": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",

        "codeception/base": "^2.2.3",
        "codeception/verify": "~0.3.1",
        "codeception/specify": "~0.4.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800,
        "fxp-asset":{
            "installer-paths": {
                "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
                "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
            }
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject": {
            "setPermission": [
                {
                    "runtime": "0777",
                    "web/assets": "0777",
                    "yii": "0755"
                }
            ],
            "generateCookieValidationKey": [
                "config/web.php"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I did it but it did not solve the problem. Can anybody help me?

Any more information you need to help me detect the problem?

Comment: you might need to add you `composer.json` file here

Comment: add it recently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`codemix/yii2-excelexport` requires a newer version of Yii than the one you have installed. You need to run `require` with `--update-with-all-dependencies` switch:

```
composer require codemix/yii2-excelexport --update-with-all-dependencies
```

The bower warning probably has nothing to do with installation fail. But you should update `fxp/composer-asset-plugin` to the last version to get rid of this warning:

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.4.4"
```